# Show grid-like data with table-look in python3-sphinx

Tags: grid, markdown, python-sphinx

I build python3-sphinx to store and show some material.

```
vim  show_table.rst
show table
=================

| #   | Expression      | Result      | Comments                                   |
| --- | --------------- | ----------- | -------------------------------------------|
| 1   | `"$a"`          | `apple`     | variables are expanded inside `""`         |
| 2   | `'$a'`          | `$a`        | variables are not expanded inside `''`     |
```

It is a standard grid table defined by markdown,instead of restructureText.
`wq` and make it :

```
make html
```

Open the `show_table.html` in browser:
[image]

It is not the format i want ,but it is in a standard html table format.Copy it and paste into my new `show_table.rst`,

```
vim show_table.rst
    show table
=================
.. raw:: html

    <table border=”1” class=”docutils”> <thead> <tr> <th>#</th> <th>Expression</th> <th>Result</th> <th>Comments</th> </tr> </thead>
    <tbody> <tr> <td>1</td> <td><code>”$a”</code></td> <td><code>apple</code></td> <td>variables are expanded inside <code>””</code>
    </td> </tr> <tr> <td>2</td> <td><code>’$a’</code></td> <td><code>$a</code></td> <td>variables are not expanded inside <code>’’</code>
    </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

`make html` ,open `show_table.html` in browser again,i get it.
[image]

It is a trivial job to convert the grid-like table into standard grid table in sphinx(Another way i don't like).Maybe to add something in `rst` file can achieve my target.

Comment: I think you Markdown table has a type, the last column should have a space the ending `-|` should be `- |`

Comment: Rename the file to show_table.md instead of show_table.rst.